# values not rendered in line chart, if xField is not given when upgraded to ext js 4.1.0 from 4.0.2a

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have problem in rendering values line chart in extjs 4.1.0. when upgraded to ext js 4.1.0 from 4.0.2a,
 values not rendered in line chart, if xField is not given but in extjs 4.02a, values are rendered if xField is not given. here is code that is working in extjs 4.0.2a:

```
{
    xtype: 'chart',
    height: 120,
    id: 'accounts-per-day-chart',
    insetPadding: 5,
    store: 'CustomersStore',
    flex: 5,
    series: [
        {
            type: 'line',
             highlight: true,
            yField: [
                'Customers'
            ],                                                                                         
            fill: true,

            selectionTolerance: 5
        }
    ],
    axes: [
        {
            type: 'Numeric',
            dashSize: 2,
            fields: [
                'Customers'
            ],
            majorTickSteps: 0,
            position: 'left',
            decimals: 0,
            minimum: 0
        }
    ]
}
```

is xField mandatory in extjs 4.1.0? please suggest solution to render values in line chart with out declaring value for xField

Comment: xField is mandatory in extjs4.1.0. because, these field values should be binded inorder to draw the chart.

Comment: is xField mandatory for only line chart? i tried with 'bar' and 'column' type without giving xField, values are rendering.

Comment: yes xField is mandatory for line chart. you can have a look at the Extjs 4.1 api.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Line

Comment: thanks for the info but i couldnt find in the extjs 4.1 api that xField is mandatory.could you please help on this regard